# TypeError with Theano/pymc (comparison operation)

Tags: numpy, theano, pymc

I run in a problem identical to the one initially reported at https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/1209, i.e TypeError on comparison between Theano object and numpy array. My code was written with the Theano object on the left of the operator and using Numpy 1.13.1

Investigating a bit I tested

```
import pymc3
with pymc3.Model() as model:
    a = pymc3.Uniform("a", 1,2)
    print 1 < a
```

which outputs, without complaining:

```
Elemwise{gt,no_inplace}.0
```

Now running

```
with pymc3.Model() as model:
    a = pymc3.Uniform("a", 1,2)
    if 1 < a:
        print "bingo"
```

produces the TypeError

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/var.pyc in __nonzero__(self)
     73     def __nonzero__(self):
     74         # Python 2.x
---> 75         return self.__bool__()
     76 
     77     def __bool__(self):
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/var.pyc in __bool__(self)
     89         else:
     90             raise TypeError(
---> 91                 "Variables do not support boolean operations."
     92             )
     93 

TypeError: Variables do not support boolean operations.
```

So my question is, how should I do this type of testing? I would like to leave my code generic since in most cases it does not run on Theano objects (of course I could have a version of this function to be used in pymc3/Theano context). For what is worth the offending code is

```
......./refsans_tools/abeles/abeles.py in guess_optimal_x(self, thickness, roughness)
   1303                                                safety=self.safety
   1304                                               )
-> 1305         if this_xmin < self._xmin:
   1306             self._xmin = this_xmin
   1307             self._xmin = - self.shift_orig
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/var.pyc in nonzero(self)
     73     def nonzero(self):
     74         # Python 2.x
---> 75         return self.bool()
     76 
     77     def bool(self):
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/var.pyc in bool(self)
     89         else:
     90             raise TypeError(
---> 91                 "Variables do not support boolean operations."
     92             )
     93 
TypeError: Variables do not support boolean operations.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
with pymc3.Model() as model:
a = pymc3.Uniform("a", 1,2)
if tt.lt(1, a):
    print "bingo"
```